# ubuntu installation on windows XP - why downloading when the iso image is in CD

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I need to install ubuntu on windows XP.
i got a cd from my friend with the ubuntu installation files
I selected the option to install ubuntu inside windows xp (d:)
but after the first steps it says "Downloading ...iso.torrent" and says 7 hours remaining

My question: when the iso file is in local cd why does the installer search for the files from the net

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this FAQ entry](http://wubi-installer.org/faq.php), question "Can I use an existing ISO/CD instead of letting Wubi download a new one?". You might have needed to put the CD in the computer first, or the ISO was not the right version for your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would start the installation again, but this time do not install from within Windows. A Wubi install is slower and less stable than a properly partitioned Ubuntu install.

Restart the computer and this time ensure that the PC boots from the CD.